# scikit-learn CountVectorizer return different sizes of vectors

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

I am trying to have a pre-processing, where I get all the documents, and build a Bag Of Words comparer.

In my init method, I create scikit-learn CountVectorizer model, and train it.

When I get 2 new documents, I need to return the cosine similarities between them.

But self.vectorizer.transform return different sizes of vectors.
This is my code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from scipy import spatial

class Bow_comparer:
    def __init__(self, texts):
        self.vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
        self.vectorizer.fit_transform(texts)

    def compare(self, doc_a, doc_b):
        doc_a_embeddings = self.vectorizer.transform([doc_a])
        doc_b_embeddings = self.vectorizer.transform([doc_b])
        return 1 - spatial.distance.cosine(doc_a_embeddings, doc_b_embeddings)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the document embeddings returned from the vectorizer are sparse matrices (csr format).

```
>>> type(doc_a_embeddings)
>>> <class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
```

This means that depending on the number of zeros in the embedding the vector size will differ.
As the spatial.distance.cosine does not support sparse arrays, you need to convert the embeddings first to arrays (or matrices). If you use embedding.toarray() (or .todense()) it will work:

```
spatial.distance.cosine(doc_a_embeddings.toarray(), doc_b_embeddings.toarray())
```